# What is the return value of a function that uses exec() like the following way?

Tags: c, return, fork, exec, return-value

I have some function, let's say func, which is looking like this:

```
int func(...)
{
    if(error(...))
        return -1;
    exec(...);
    return -1; //exec failed
}
```

So func returns -1 in case of error, but what does it return in case of success?

Is it good practice or error prone if I do something like this in the main function?

```
if(func(...) == -1)
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
//do something
```

Comment: "but what does it return in case of success?" Nothing, because exec doesn't return on success.

Comment: Read [an `exec` (and family) manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html).

Comment: I assumed this, thank you. So would this be problematic with the if-statement below?

Comment: Why test for `-1` at all? Just `exit` unconditionally.

Comment: Because I have to free all dynamically allocated resources in the main before termination. There are many so I don't want to but this in func().

Comment: `exec` family of functions replace the current program within the same process (simplified), so if it is successful the code after the `exec` simply isn't there any more.

Comment: Free the resources *before* you do the `exec`.

Comment: But if it's not successful, the code is there. So, unfortunately, my mind tricked me a bit. Freeing before the exec is the obvious solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

exec() will return only in case of an error while making another process. If everything was successful while making another process with exec(), then exec() will never return. Lets say you made your process successfully with exec() but segmentation fault occurred in some point of that process. exec() will not return -1 in this case.  Read man 3 exec

Comment: You use `wait` or `waitpid` only after a `fork`, using it after an `exec` is useless.

Comment: Alright thank you  i am new to system programming i did not know that. I will edit my answer

Comment: I will read again chapter about exec from the book the linux programming interface.. guess i did not pay much attention last time

Comment: `fork` (there are several versions, including `vfork`) creates a new process in (almost) the same state as the original, including the position in the program.  You use the return code from `fork` to determine if you are in parent or child.  `exec` (again, several versions) replaces the program in the *current* process (simplified).  Usually we do a `fork` and then in the *child* do an `exec`.  In the *parent* we do a `wait` or `waitpid`.

Comment: Thats why i thought i should use wait() after exec()... because i was always using exec() in fork().. Thank you :D now i understand it batter

Comment: It is strange the first time you see it, but once you understand it then all kinds of other things make sense.  For example, in the child then the `pid` changes and the original `pid` becomes the `ppid`.  On `exec` the environment block and the file descriptor table are not overwritten (though see `FD_CLOEXEC`).  That's how inheritance and redirection (> in the shell) works.  This is the way UNIX systems have always behaved (at least since the late 1970s).

Comment: I am aware of that. I assume this is not a place to ask, but could you help me find some good projects that will make me a batter system programmer? I am doing all the examples in TLPI book but it is not enough, and i don't have much experience to think of something on my own

Comment: Systems programming is specialised, I suggest you are the only person who can say what is relevant.  Don't try to learn everything at once.  A simple example would be to write a client-server system passing small files between processes on the same machine.  You can try using various IPC methods (message queues, named pipes, sockets) and get to grips with synchronisation (semaphores).